# What jQuery versions are used by SE sites?

Tags: support, technology, jquery

This is probably an XY problem, but I am focusing on my solution.

[It's known](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258288/5958455) that China has blocked off all of Google, including `ajax.googleapis.com` where SE loads jQuery library. For some reasons, I can't use a VPN or a proxy at the time, so I decided to go with [Resource Override](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resource-override/pkoacgokdfckfpndoffpifphamojphii), a popular Chrome extensions that allow users to redirect URLs on their side.

At first I used a reverse proxy provided by my school club, but the server for the reverse proxy is rather unstable, so I went for the "URL → File" option.

With this way, I need to know what exact versions of jQuery SE employs, so I can redirect the correct URLs. Currently it seems to be 1.12.4, but I have also seen other versions in the past, like 1.7.x, 2.x or 3.x

Is there a complete list of what versions of jQuery that SE is using?

> [image]

Comment: You could use [decentraleyes](https://decentraleyes.org/). It loads scripts like jQuery from an internal storage instead of CDN's like Google. Does it automatically too, so you don't have to dig through site code and find versions of scripts to replace

Comment: Where would it get the scripts from though?

Comment: I mean Princess Luna's option - it would need to pull in the scripts from somewhere that works

Comment: @JourneymanGeek looks like [the jQuery (and other resources) are already bundled in the extension](https://git.synz.io/Synzvato/decentraleyes/tree/master/resources)?

Comment: Related: *[Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208)* (has *"The following sites should be accessible"*)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek as `and myself` mentioned, they're in the extension. it also speeds up websites because it doesn't actually download them from a CDN. No CDN download => no blocks. It also covers jquery, which means using it would load jquery from a local repo rather than from the Google CDN, which means the site would work with jquery even if the hosting CDN is blocked

Answer (score 2):

You can try special extension "[Wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com)":
<sup>You seem to be correct with Jquery version.</sup>
[image]
You can try dealing with this extension, so that you will always know what Jquery library SE is using. They have [API](https://www.wappalyzer.com/api)s for that, but they are not free.